# Complexity of Fibonacci Fast Recursive Program

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, fibonacci

```
def fastfib(n, fib_dict = {0: 1, 1: 1}):
    if n not in fib_dict:
         fib_dict[n] = fastfib(n-1, fib_dict) + fastfib(n-2, fib_dict)
    return fib_dict[n]
```

I think the complexity here is n^2, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are filling a dictionary with *n* values, the lower bound is *O(n)*. However, since you're only doing constant-time operations for each *n*, (Pythons dictionary lookup operation is *O(1)*, though amortized), this algorithm should be *O(n)* (amortized). This technique of saving already computed values in a table is called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).